# Getting segfault when using shared pointer as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Lotus {
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Lotus> LotusPtr;

class A
{
  public:
  LotusPtr a;
  A()
  {
      a = std::make_shared<Lotus>();
      a->m_x = 55;
      a->m_y = 66;
  }
  void baz(LotusPtr q) {
    q = a;
  }      
};

int main() 
{
    // Initialized to nullptr
    LotusPtr p;
    A *a = new A();
    
    a->baz(p);
    
    std::cout << "p : m_x" << p->m_x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "p : m_y" << p->m_y << std::endl;

    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I am getting a segfault. Can anyone explain why I am getting this?

Comment: `baz` modifies a copy of `p`, change it to take a reference: `void baz(LotusPtr& q)`

Comment: This is a mistake that beginners often make with regular pointers. Surprising to see a smart pointer version. To paraphrase, there's nothing special about smart pointers.